# Azure Policy to audit app service authentication

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-management

How can I create a Azure policy to audit app services authentication? I would like to enforce that all app services have Active Directory Authentication enabled, and flag other authentication methods as non-compliant.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible today.  You can audit your app services to check that *authentication* is enabled.  But you cannot specify a specific identity provider as part of the policy.

```
{
    "if": {
        "allOf": [
            {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
            },
            {
                "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/siteAuthEnabled",
                "equals": "false"
            }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
    }
}
```

A policy to insure that Azure AD is the identity provider, you would need something like this (which won't work today). Since there is not an *alias* to support the field `Microsoft.Web/sites/config/siteAuthSettings.issuer`, it won't work.

```
{
    "if": {
        "allOf": [
            {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
            },
            {
                "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/siteAuthEnabled",
                "equals": "false"
            },
            {
                "field": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config/siteAuthSettings.issuer",
                "like": "https://sts.windows.net/*"
            }
        ]
    },
    "then": {
        "effect": "audit"
    }
}
```

The guidance is to submit an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/blob/master/1-contribution-guide/request-alias.md) to request an alias be added, which it appears you did already.  Posting it [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy/issues/207) in case others want to follow it.

Comment: Thanks @Rick-Rainey ! You're right, I ended up reaching the same conclusion and submitted the issue.